# existence of perfect matching in a bipartite graph with special conditions

Tags: graph-theory

Claim: Suppose $G(V, E)$ is a bipartite graph where $A\cup B = V$, $|A|=|B|$, every vertex has a even degree $(deg(v) \in \{2,4,6,...\})$ and no vertex is isolated.
if this is the case, you can always find a perfect matching in $G$.

can someone give a simple prove or disprove for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Not true.** Disproof by counterexample:

[image]

The top $4$ blue vertices and the bottom $4$ red vertices do not have enough choices between them in the other part to produce a perfect matching.